# Add a progress bar to a Job in RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp, jobs

I have a time consuming job in my RCp application in which I read out a big database and save it in a file. I am running this job in a separate thread so that the UI of my app is not blocked but I dont know how to add a progress bar to this task

My code:

```
public class MirrorFeatureModel extends Job {

protected class MutexRule implements ISchedulingRule {
    public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
         return rule == this;
      }
    public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
         return rule == this;
      }
}

private String source;
private String template;
private String target;

public MirrorFeatureModel(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public MirrorFeatureModel(String source, String template, String target){
    super("Mirroring SWA Model");
    this.source = source;
    this.template = template;
    this.target = target;
}

public void run() {
    this.schedule();
}


@Override
protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)  {

    ILog logView = Activator.getDefault().getLog();
    String connectionString = this.source;
    String emptyEAP = this.template;
    String target = this.target;

    try{

        monitor.beginTask("Copying swa model to local", 1);
        new Mirror(connectionString, emptyEAP,target).run();
        monitor.worked(1);

    }catch(final Exception e) {

        logView.log(new Status(Status.ERROR, null , "Failed to create local SAM instance", e));         


        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                MessageDialog.openError(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().getActiveShell(), "Failed to create local SAM instance", e.getMessage());
            }

        });
        return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
    }       

    return Status.OK_STATUS;
  }


}
```

Mirror.run() Method

```
 public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {

    try{

        if (monitor != null)
            monitor.subTask("Creating directory for eap file");

        File tempTarget=File.createTempFile("eap-mirror", "eap");           
        if (monitor != null)
            monitor.worked(1);  

        try {

            if (monitor != null)
                monitor.subTask("Establising connection");

            this.source=DriverManager.getConnection(com.intel.imc.swa.easql.EaDbStringParser.eaDbStringToJdbc(sourceString));
            this.source.setReadOnly(true);

            if(monitor != null) 
                monitor.worked(1);

            FileUtils.copyFile(new File(templateFileString), tempTarget);

            if (monitor != null)
                monitor.subTask("Opening database"); 

            this.target=Database.open(tempTarget,false,false);

            if(monitor != null)     
                monitor.worked(1);

            if (monitor != null)
                monitor.subTask("Mirroring tables"); 

            Collection<String> tables=selectTables(source);
            long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (String tableName : tables) {
                long tTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                Table table=target.getTable(tableName);
                System.out.print("Mirroring table "+tableName+"...");
                table.setOverrideAutonumber(true);
                copyTable(table, source, target);
                    System.out.println(" took "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-tTime));
            }

            System.out.println("Done. Overall time: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
            if(monitor != null)     
                monitor.worked(1); 

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I add a progress bar in this class that shows me the progress of this job

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally jobs show a progress indicator in the progress view and in the status line at the bottom of the main window.

If you call `setUser(true)` before `schedule()` then the job will show a pop-up progress dialog if the job runs for more than a few seconds.

To show job progress you must specify the total amount of work on the `beginTask` call

```
monitor.beginTask("...", total work);
```

and then you must call `monitor.worked(xxx)` each time you have done part of the work.

Comment: On the bottom it is showing the progress but always 0% even if the job is running

Comment: setUSer() now shows me the dialog for the progress but is not showing me the percentage of the work done. How can I do that ?

Comment: You must use monitor.beginTask to say how much work will be done and then call monitor.worked to update the progress - added to answer

Comment: That is for you to decide based on the work your job is going to do. If you were going to create 100 files you might make the total 100 and call worked(1) after each file is created.

Comment: I create only one file And I have already called both the beginTask and worked methods but the progress bar in the dailog is not showing any progress it apears when the job starts and close when the job is done

Comment: You only get progress shown when you call `worked` - if you only have one call to that you won't see any progress. It is up to you to divide up the work in the job in to small enough steps for progress to be shown.

Comment: but the job I am doing is in new Mirror(connectionString, emptyEAP,target).run(); which is another class and when its done I return tomy job class but when its running the job i want to show the progress

Comment: You can't magically report progress if you don't have anything telling you about the progress

Comment: Thanks :) I will try , what I understood from your explanation is that in the class where I create temporary files and copy the data base I have to call the worked method to indicate the  progress. right?

Comment: Kindly check the updated code... In my Mirror.run method the progress bar goes to 100% as soon the job starts

Comment: Your `beginTask` call is still specifying 1 for the total work - it must be the total of all the `worked(n)` calls you are going to make.